# Error starting new Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have the following method to move onto a new `Activity`:

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FacebookHandler.class);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String message = editText1.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(FacebookHandler.class);                     
}
```

The last line, `startActivity(FacebookHandler.class);` gives me the following error message:

```
StartActivity(android.content.intent) in Activity cannot be applied.
```

I've tried moving it around, but I'm out of ideas for how to get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such a method as `startActivity(Class<?> cls)` for [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) which, for instance, an [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) are inherited from. Signature of one of the methods that starts an `Activity` is [`startActivity(Intent intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)).

That said, it should be

```
startActivity(intent);
```

instead.